# Gradle task to execute android zipalign

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, zipalign

I would like to build a gradle Exec task that would run android's zipalign on my signed apk file, and then validates the the alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variables**:

- ANDROID_HOME - path to android SDK
- ZIPALIGN_PATH - path to zipalign executable, relative to the
- ANDROID_HOME buildDir - gradle's build directory
- OUTPUT_APK_PATH - the directory of created apk files
- APK_FILE_TO_ALIGN - the apk that you want to perform the zipalign on (should be signed)
- APK_FILE_NAME - the name of the file after zipalign

**zipalign task:**

```
task zipAlign(type: Exec) {

        executable "${ANDROID_HOME}${ZIPALIGN_PATH}"
        args "-f",  "-v", "4", "${buildDir}${OUTPUT_APK_PATH}${APK_FILE_TO_ALIGN}", "${buildDir}${OUTPUT_APK_PATH}${APK_FILE_NAME}"

}
```

**zipalign verification task** (note that this task depends on the zipalign task):

```
task verifyZipAlign(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'zipAlign') {

        executable "${ANDROID_HOME}${ZIPALIGN_PATH}"
        args "-c",  "-v", "4", "${buildDir}${OUTPUT_APK_PATH}${APK_FILE_NAME}"

}
```

Comment: After gradle version 2.2.0 it only produces zip aligned APKs, so this is completely unnecessary: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37103802

Comment: Not really, if you make changes to the APK you will need to zip align again

Comment: Zipalign does verification automatically. There's a nice comment in source code "Trust, but verify".